# How to use sftp in cfncluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, sftp

How can I transfer files using `sftp` to and from an AWS cluster created using `cfncluster`.

I have tried

`sftp -i path/to/mykey.pem ec2-user@<MASTER.NODE.IP>`

which produces

`Connection closed`

I also tried using Transmit and CyberDuck without any luck.

If you know a way of transfering files to and from cfncluster that does not use `sftp` please share that too.

Comment: Can you ssh into the master?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh into the master using `ssh -i path/to/mykey.pem ec2-user@<MASTER.NODE.IP>`

Comment: Can you post the the output from the sftp -v ....

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post_intall variable in your config file that will include an extra script to be run after cfncluster deployment
`post_intall=https://s3-eu-west-aws-xxxxx/your_script.sh`

with your script being like:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sed -i '/Subsystem\ sftp.*$/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo sed -i '$iSubsystem sftp internal-sftp' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo service sshd restart
```

it's quite rough but it works...